# Generic Brushless motors equivalence for calculations with ecalc

Tags: brushless-motors

The [ecalc](https://www.ecalc.ch/) website is very useful to do estimations for models, however I haven't found how to choose correctly the motor options for generic brushless motors like these

[image]
[image]

In motor choice option there are many famous brand motors but I cannot find these, and I haven't clear how to set generic motors (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the manufacturer is "suppo". The 2212/13 (1000kV) is available in the free version

Any equivalent 2212 will be close enough for calculations, and you can get wattage information by matching the effective final RPM, if you can't find a matching kV. For example:

I have a 1400kv 2212, but I can only find a 1000kV 2212 on ecalc. I want to run it on 3S (12V).

Use the 1000kV 2212, and run it on 4S (3S x 1.4 ~= 4S) (16V). The effective final RPM is the same, so the wattage will be the same. The current will decrease by 1.4 to compensate for the changed voltage, so you'll have to do that math accordingly. Keep in mind in this case your current will be *much higher* than what ecalc is showing you. Current creates heat, and ecalc will warn you about this, but *not in your case*. Exercise caution that you don't overdo it on current since you won't be seeing these warnings.